# View only properties (eg: IsSelected) and the Model in MVVM

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, model

Consider a WPF app that is being written using MVVM. The app needs to display a list of Employees (FirstName, LastName, Title) and you can select multiple to delete.

The model in this case would be "**Employee**" and it would implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

The View would be the "**EmployeeListView**" which would implement the XAML to display a collection of Employees.

The ViewModel would be "**EmployeeListViewModel**" which would expose an **ObservableCollection**, that can be bound to the **EmployeeListView**.

My question is: Where should the "**IsSelected**" property live?

1. **In the Model?** (I dont like this idea, as the model now is exposing a property that is only required by a view and has nothing to do with the actual domain object, also, this property would be useless, if I implemented the view differently and didnt allow deletion of multiple employees at once).
2. In the "**EmployeeListViewModel**" as a separate Dictionary collection, that would track whether an employee is selected or not? (Or even just a HashSet containing all selected employees). I dont like this much as the binding in the view is no longer straight forward.
3. **Implement a separate EmployeeViewModel**, that wraps the Employee object and exposes the IsSelected property. The EmployeeListViewModel then will expose its collection as a ObservableCollection. I like this solution the best, but I always thought that there is one ViewModel per View and in this case, I have 2 view-models for my view. ***Is that a deviation from the MVVM pattern or is this the typical way to implement MVVM?*** (references?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a reusable Generic SelectableItem that wraps each item in the EmployeeList:

Simple example:

```
public class SelectableItem<T>: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsSelected {get;set;} //PropertyChanged(), etc

    public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

then in the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<SelectableItem<Employee>> Employees {get;set;}
```

and in the View:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Value.FullName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can retrieve all selected employees just by:

```
var selectedemployees = Employees.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: I do like this solution. But although I do ask about implementing IsSelected, my question is also about whether its kosher is MVVM to have multiple ViewModels being used by one View. Also, isnt SelectableItem a ViewModel and in which case this is similar to my solution #3, but just implemented in a more generic way? (What if I had more UI specific items to track - IsChecked, IsSelected, etc, and not all UIs would need these different properties to be tracked)

Comment: It is totally acceptable to have multiple VM in on View. In fact, you can think that every control on a View is a View itself. The best example is when you have a DataGrid where every row will have his own VM.

Comment: If there's one thing I could go back and tell myself 5 years ago it's NEVER BE AFRAID TO MAKE SOMETHING A VIEW MODEL!

Comment: I prefer `Item` to `Value` since `Value` may be confused with a nullable type