# Get DataTemplate from data object in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, datatemplate

I have a `ListBox` whose `ItemTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="local:Column">
    <utils:EditableTextBlock x:Name="editableTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

`Column` is a simple class which looks like this:

```
public Column(string name, bool isVisibleInTable)
{
    Name = name;
    IsVisibleInTable = isVisibleInTable;
}

public string Name { get; set; }
public bool IsVisibleInTable { get; set; }
```

The `EditableTextBlock` is a `UserControl` that turns into a `TextBox` when double clicked and turns back into a `TextBlock` when Lost Focus. It also has a Property called `IsInEditMode` which is by default false. When it is true, `TextBox` is shown.

**The Question:**
The `ItemsSouce` of the ListBox is an `ObservableCollection<Column>`. I have a button which adds new `Column`s to the collection. But my problem is that I want `IsInEditMode` to be turned true for newly added `EditableTextBlock`s by *that Button*. But I can only access `Column` in the ViewModel. How will I access the `EditableTextBlock` of the specified `Column` in the `ItemsSource` collection?

The only solution I can come up with is deriving a class from `Column` and adding a property for that (eg: name: `IsInEditMode`) (Or maybe a wrapper class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179058/3964654)'s a similar answer which suggestes using a wrapper class) and Binding to that property in the DataTemplate like so:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="local:DerivedColumn">
    <utils:EditableTextBlock x:Name="editableTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But I don't want this. I want some way to do this in XAML without deriving classes and adding unnecessary code. (And also adhering to MVVM rules)

Comment: Why not just add the property in the Column class, bind it to IsInEditMode DP and make a ctor with an optionnal parameter to set the mode? You would only have to create a Column and pass true to the ctor in the Command behind the button

Comment: I know. That is what I did using the derived class. But I will be using this Column class in other places as well . And in those places, IsInEditMode property will be useless.
Is there any XAML only solution?

Comment: Well, I just did a wrapper class instead of deriving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have scope to add a new dependency property to the `EditableTextBlock` user control you could consider adding one that has the name `StartupInEditMode`, defaulting to `false` to keep the existing behavior.

The `Loaded` handler for the `UserControl` could then determine the status of `StartupInEditMode` to decide how to initially set the value of `IsInEditMode`.

```cs
//..... Added to EditableTextBlock user control
    public bool StartupInEdit
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(StartupInEditProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartupInEditProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartupInEditProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartupInEdit", typeof(bool), typeof(EditableTextBlock ), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private void EditableTextBlock_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsInEditMode = StartupInEditMode;
    }
```

For controls already in the visual tree the changing value of `StartupInEdit` does not matter as it is only evaluated once on creation.  This means you can populate the collection of the `ListBox` where each `EditableTextBlock` is not in edit mode, then swap the `StartupInEditmMode` mode to `True` when you start adding new items.  Then each new `EditableTextBlock` control starts in the edit mode.

You could accomplish this switch in behavior by specifying a `DataTemplate` where the `Binding` of this new property points to a variable of the view and not the collection items.

```xaml
    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Column">
      <utils:EditableTextBlock x:Name="editableTextBlock"
            Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            StartupInEditMode="{Binding ANewViewProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

You need to add a property to the parent `Window` (or `Page` or whatever is used as the containter for the view) called `ANewViewProperty` in this example. This value could be part of your view model if you alter the binding to `{Binding DataContext.ANewViewProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}`.

This new property (`ANewViewProperty`) does not even need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as the binding will get the initial value as it is creating the new `EditableTextBlock` control and if the value changes later it has no impact anyway.

You would set the value of `ANewViewProperty` to `False` as you load up the `ListBox` `ItemSource` initially.  When you press the button to add a new item to the list set the value of `ANewViewProperty` to `True` meaning the control that will now be created starting up in edit mode.

## Update: The C#-only, View-only alternative

The code-only, view-only alternative (similar to user2946329's answer)is to hook to the `ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged` handler that will trigger when a new item is added.  Once triggered and you are now acting on new items (via Boolean `DetectingNewItems`) which finds the first descendant `EditableTextBlock` control for the appropriate `ListBoxItem` visual container for the item newly added.  Once you have a reference for the control, alter the `IsInEditMode` property.

```cs
//.... View/Window Class

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
    }

    private void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if ((e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add) && DetectingNewItems)
      {
        var listboxitem = LB.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(e.Position.Index + 1) as ListBoxItem;

        var editControl = FindFirstDescendantChildOf<EditableTextBlock>(listboxitem);
        if (editcontrol != null) editcontrol.IsInEditMode = true;
      }
    }

    public static T FindFirstDescendantChildOf<T>(DependencyObject dpObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dpObj == null) return null;

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dpObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dpObj, i);
            if (child is T) return (T)child;

            var obj = FindFirstChildOf<T>(child);

            if (obj != null) return obj;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

### Update #2 (based on comments)

Add a property to the view that refers back to the the ViewModel assuming you keep a reference to the View Model in the `DataContext`:-

```c#
    .....  // Add this to the Window/Page

    public bool DetectingNewItems
    {
        get
        {
            var vm = DataContext as MyViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
                return vm.MyPropertyOnVM;
            return false;
        }
    }

    .....
```

Comment: Where is DetectingNewItems defined?

Comment: `DetectingNewItems` was a made up Boolean (a field in your view) you can use to mark the point when you want to start noticing new items.  It is `False` when you want to populate the collection initially so the control will not be in edit mode if you are restoring the view from a datasource.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test this later today and inform you

Comment: How would you tell view to toggle DetectingNewItems without viewmodel not knowing what the view is?

Comment: I'd deduced you might be using MVVM but it is hard to see here how specifically you are doing it (loose MVVM, MVVM-light, full MVVM), I'll add an example of a property `DetectingNewItems` that points to a ViewModel property assuming you use the `DataContext` to hold the VM

Comment: That clears things out. Thanks a lot :)  btw, wouldn't it be better to use `dynamic` instead of casting with as?

Answer (score 1):

To get an element inside a template and change it's properties in code you need [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName Method (String, FrameworkElement)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListBoxItem yourListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(yourListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
    ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(yourListBoxItem);
    DataTemplate myDataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
    EditableTextBlock editable = (EditableTextBlock) myDataTemplate.FindName("editableTextBlock", contentPresenter);
    //Do stuff with EditableTextBlock
    editable.IsInEditMode = true;
}
```